# database changes not reflected in JSF 2 web application

Tags: sql-server-2008, jsf-2, intellij-idea, tomcat7

When i make a change directly in my database (SQL Server), like adding a new row to a table,  the changes are not reflected in my web app (tried refreshing the browser) until i run my app again (in intellij with tomcat plugin).

if i add a row from my app i can see it inmediatly on my database admin, but the other way around doesn't work.

this is my persitence.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="Frutemu" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
        <jta-data-source>openjpa</jta-data-source>
        <class>model2.AnalisisProcesosEntity</class>
        <class>model2.AnalisisProcesosDetalleEntity</class>
        <class>model2.AnalisisProcesosPesosEntity</class>
        <class>model2.AnalisisRecepcionesEntity</class>
        <class>model2.AnalisisRecepcionesDetallesEntity</class>
        <class>model2.CalibresEntity</class>
        <class>model2.CalidadDefectosEntity</class>
        <class>model2.CalidadesEntity</class>
        <class>model2.CamarasEntity</class>
        <class>model2.DespachosEntity</class>
        <class>model2.DespachosDetalleEntity</class>
        <class>model2.EspeciesEntity</class>
        <class>model2.ExportadorasEntity</class>
        <class>model2.InspeccionesEntity</class>
        <class>model2.InspeccionesDespachosEntity</class>
        <class>model2.InspeccionesDespachosDetalleEntity</class>
        <class>model2.InspeccionesDetalleEntity</class>
        <class>model2.InspeccionesPalletsEntity</class>
        <class>model2.InspeccionesPalletsDetalleEntity</class>
        <class>model2.InspeccionesResultadoEntity</class>
        <class>model2.PalletsEntity</class>
        <class>model2.PalletsDetalleEntity</class>
        <class>model2.PlantasEntity</class>
        <class>model2.PlantasEmbalajeEntity</class>
        <class>model2.ProcesosEntity</class>
        <class>model2.ProcesosDetalleEntity</class>
        <class>model2.ProductoresEntity</class>
        <class>model2.ProductoresExportadorasEntity</class>
        <class>model2.RecepcionesEntity</class>
        <class>model2.RecepcionesDetalleEntity</class>
        <class>model2.SysdiagramsEntity</class>
        <class>model2.TemporadasEntity</class>
        <class>model2.TiposEmbalajeEntity</class>
        <class>model2.TiposProductoEntity</class>
        <class>model2.UsuariosEntity</class>
        <class>model2.VariedadesEntity</class>
        <class>model2.VistaProcesosEntity</class>
        <class>model2.VistaRecepcionesEntity</class>

        <properties>

            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:55334;databaseName=Frutemu;integratedSecurity=true"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionUserName" value=""/>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionPassword" value=""/>

            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings"
                      value="buildSchema(SchemaAction='add,OpenJPATables=true',ForeignKeys=true)"/>
            <!--property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema(SchemaAction='add,OpenJPATables=true',ForeignKeys=true)"/-->
            <property name="openjpa.DynamicEnhancementAgent" value="true"/>
            <property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=WARN, Runtime=INFO, Tool=INFO, SQL=ERROR"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionFactoryProperties" value="PrettyPrint=true, PrettyPrintLineLength=72, PrintParameters=true, MaxActive=10, MaxIdle=5, MinIdle=2, MaxWait=60000"/>
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.MySQLDictionary"/>
            <property name="openjpa.DataCache" value="true"/>
            <property name="openjpa.QueryCache" value="true"/>


        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

this is the bean from where i get the data to display in my view:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "recepciones")
@ViewScoped
public class RecepcionesBean {

        private List<VistaRecepcionesEntity> recepciones;

        @PostConstruct
        public void init(){
            recepciones=new ArrayList<VistaRecepcionesEntity>();
            recepciones= RecepcionesDAO.getALL();
        }

        public List<VistaRecepcionesEntity> getRecepciones() {
            return recepciones;
        }

        public void setRecepciones(List<VistaRecepcionesEntity> recepciones) {
            this.recepciones = recepciones;
        }


        }
    }
```

Comment: Show us how you desplay your files. My best guess is that you need to refresh your entities.

Comment: i added the bean from where i get the data for my view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with openJPA. But the option `openjpa.DataCache` seem to indicate that you have a cache activated for data. In this case, there are several strategies.

1. If you don't really need to update your database directly "by hand", then don't. Or deactivate the cache. One of these two is probably the safest or at least simplest.
2. Otherwise, you probably need to customize the cache strategy. You could have the cache invalidated after X minutes (and accept the fact that you might have stale data for up to X minutes in your app).
3. Or you can also code a page that would allow you to manually clear the cache. You could then invoke it every time you have manually updated the database.